Instance group is not being updated
When I go to update the minimum number  of instance and maximum number of instance then I got the following error.
Failed to update instance group xxx-instance-group: Internal error. Please try again or contact Google Support. (Code: '616599588FD78.937C2F2.7E0A7CE1')

I tried to check another instance group that has some minimum and maximum number of instance just         try to save it, getting the same error.
I tried to check my quota in the same region it is also within the limit


Hi Brajesh this small piece of error code doesn't take us any where, there might be multiple reasons like machine type limits, resources exhaustion in that particular zone, network related error and it can also be a temporary glitch. To get full details on this issue instead of pasting the error message displayed on the console you need to go through the compute engine logs in stack driver.
